# How to export html table to excel?

Tags: asp.net

I want to export html table(not grid) to excel from my content page.I know how to export grid to excel.Same way or diffrent?

Comment: you can use excel libraray, download it from codeplex.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364107/export-html-table-to-excel-using-asp-net

Comment: If you just need to export "simple data", I would recommend [Excel-friendly] CSV and not the various HTML [hacks] floating about .. it works well here.

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Comment: @Kev,if u see properly,I already shared my code.

Answer (score 2):

Try using following code this will help you:

```
 private void ExportToExcel(string strFileName,Table dg)
    {
            Response.Clear();
            System.IO.StringWriter oStringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();

            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + strFileName + ".xls");

            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.Charset = "";
            this.EnableViewState = false;

            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter oHtmlTextWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter);
            dg.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);
            Response.Write(oStringWriter.ToString());
            Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: good one.....a detailed answer