# how to format excel sheet according to property value of an object?

Tags: c#, .net, excel

i need to create and download a excel sheet in c# asp.net. I used writing Range. because it is fast. but i need to format the excel sheet. According to a property(usercolor) of the user object, i need to color the row. but when writing to range how can i do that?

i am using this code to write
       var startCell = (Range)sheet.Cells[2, 1];
       var endCell = new object();
       endCell = (Range)sheet.Cells[(usersList.Count + 2), noofcolums];
       var writeRange = sheet.get_Range(startCell, endCell);
       writeRange.Value2 = data;

data is a TwoDimensionalObject. it is created by user object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any way to use Object property to map with row color in range writing way. I need to write cell by cell. but it is very slow. So i used creating html file(html table) and convert it to excel document. it is not slow also. Thank you very much for all replies

Answer (score 2):

As an additional comment: Do NOT use Excel in a server inevironment. It is slow and Excel might spawn error-windows at any time, causing a hang. This cannot be circumvented in a clean way - even Microsoft agrees and does not support office in a server model.
You might try epplus, a free reading / writing library for excel. It is fast , supports formatting and is way nicer to program than excel interop.

Comment: but i need support 2003. epplus support 2007 excel

Comment: There are some other packages in the wild, please search stackoverflow for examples.
Aspose cells could be good, but you have to pay for it.
Using excel is probably a last ditch alternative...
As a question: way do you have to support the old 2003 format?

Comment: it is my client requirement

Answer (score 0):

To color any Row in Excel

oRange.get_Range("A1","X1").Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToWin32(Color.Orange);

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks for your response. but i need to know how to get proper rows and only color them. Is there any way to querying according to object.

Answer (score 0):

please refer this [Export HTML Table to Excel using ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364107/export-html-table-to-excel-using-asp-net/9810842#9810842)