# Export HTML table to Excel. Table with rowspans and Colspan in c# or jquery

Tags: c#, jquery

I want to export following html table to excel.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While a great resource, people aren't here to do your work for you. Have a go, and come back if you run into a __specific programming problem__.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export HTML Table to Excel using ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364107/export-html-table-to-excel-using-asp-net)