# not valid format or extension when open the exported Excel sheet from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to export HTML from my ASP.NET application into excel file using `Response` as per this solution:
[Export HTML Table to Excel using ASP.NET.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364107/export-html-table-to-excel-using-asp-net)

This is exactly my function that export the HTML table when click export button:

```
protected void exportBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string filename = "Results_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy")+".xlsx";
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/x-msexcel";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", filename));
            Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
            resultTable.RenderControl(hw);
            Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
            Response.End();

        }
```

After exporting done when i try to open the generated `.xlsx` file it shows this message: 
[image: Error Message]

Any idea how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) for example. All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.

Comment: @VDWWD but it used to work previously, i couldn't figure what is the issue with this

Comment: It doesn't matter if it worked before. It shouldn't work.

Answer (score -1):

The simple solution is to change `ContentType` from `"application/x-msexcel"` to `"application/vnd.ms-excel"` and use `.xls` as extension instead of using `.xlsx`.

**The final code will be:**

```
protected void exportBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string filename = "Results_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy")+".xls";
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", filename));
            Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
            resultTable.RenderControl(hw);
            Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
            Response.End();

        }
```

Comment: Why use XLS? It's not an Excel file.

Comment: @mason idk it works, i searched for this extension and found that it is excel file https://fileinfo.com/extension/xls is int't it ?

Comment: No. Simply throwing an XLS extension onto a file doesn't make it an Excel file. It makes it an HTML file masquerading as an Excel file. It's a dirty hack.

Comment: @mason i got it, any better suggestion ?

Comment: VDWWD already covered the proper solution in the comments on the question.