# Export html table to excel file in asp.net core

Tags: html, asp.net-core, html-table, export, export-to-excel

I want to convert a html table of a view to excel format file.
somthing like that:

```
@model DataTable
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive  table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr >
        @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
        {
            <th class="border-white">@col.Caption</th>
        }
    </tr>

</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
    {
        <tr>
            @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
            {
                <td class="border-white">@row[col.ColumnName]</td>
            }
        </tr>
    }

</tbody>
```

I searched in web, but I don't find anything.
Information about this issue limit to export a SQL table or a model class to excel file.
Can anyone help me, how I export html table to excel?

Comment: A hint perhaps: write a csv file.  Excel will be perfectly happy with that.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364107/export-html-table-to-excel-using-asp-net) will work for you?

Comment: @berkansasmaz This solution works on asp.net and doesn't work on asp.net core.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Thanks  for your hint. I find my answer.

Comment: Ah, I've seen your answer. You should have said "download" in your question! ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could refer the following method to export the table to the excel file.

1. Without using Client-Side Library or Server-Side package, and use the following code to export html table to excel.

   ```
    @using System.Data
    @model DataTable
    <table id="tblExport" class="table table-hover table-responsive  table-striped">
        @*table content*@ 
    </table>

    <input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('tblExport', 'W3C Example Table')" value="Export to Excel">
    @section scripts{ 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var tableToExcel = (function () {
                var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
                    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
                    , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
                    , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
                return function (table, name) {
                    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
                    var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
                    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
                }
            })()
        </script>
    }
   ```

   [Note] By using this method, it will export a `.xls` excel file. You will get a Warning message from Microsoft Excel application when you try to open the generated Excel file. This Warning is shown because the generated file is not a valid Excel format as the plugin simply exports the HTML content to an Excel file.

   The excel content like this:

   [image]
2. using FileSaver.js plugin and TableExport plugin to export html table to excel.

   Right click the **wwwroot** folder, then click **Add** and **Client-Side Library...**, enter `FileSaver.js` and click the Install button to install the library. Do the same with the TableExport plugin.

   Then, using the following code export data.

   ```
    @using System.Data
    @model DataTable
    <table id="tblExport" class="table table-hover table-responsive  table-striped">
        @*table content*@ 
    </table>
    @section scripts{
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/TableExport/css/tableexport.min.css" />
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/Blob.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/xls.core.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/FileSaver.js/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/TableExport/js/tableexport.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                var tables = $("#tblExport").tableExport({
                    bootstrap: true,
                    headings: true,
                    footers: true,
                    formats: ["xlsx", "xls", "csv", "txt"],
                    fileName: "MyExcel",
                    position: "top",
                    ignoreRows: null,
                    ignoreCols: null,
                    ignoreCSS: ".tableexport-ignore",
                    emptyCSS: ".tableexport-empty",
                    trimWhitespace: true
                });
            });
        </script> 
    }
   ```

   You can create a Blob.js and xls.core.min.js file, and add content from the js content in these links: [Blob.js](https://jsfiddle.net/o1skezyj/3/) and [xls.core.min.js](https://jsfiddle.net/o1skezyj/2/).

   The web page looks like this:

   [image]

   By using this method, you can export the table to excel, csv and txt file.
3. using [ClosedXML package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/). This is an server-side method.

   Install the ClosedXML package via NuGet Package Manager.

   Create a action to export the DataTable to excel, code as below:

   ```
    //index page: display the table data.
    public IActionResult ExportExcel()
    {
        var custTable = CreateDataTable();
        return View(custTable);
    }
    public IActionResult ExportDataTabletoExcel()
    {
        var dt = CreateDataTable();
        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                wb.SaveAs(stream);
                return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Grid.xlsx");
            }
        }
    }
    public DataTable CreateDataTable()
    {
        // Create a new DataTable.    
        DataTable custTable = new DataTable("Customers");
        DataColumn dtColumn;
        DataRow myDataRow;
        ... //add columns and rows.
        return custTable;
    }
   ```

   Code in the view page:

   ```
    @using System.Data
    @model DataTable
    <table id="tblExport" class="table table-hover table-responsive  table-striped">
        @*table content*@ 
    </table>

    <a href='@Url.Action("ExportDataTabletoExcel","Home")'> export to excel</a>
   ```

   By using this method, it will generate a `.xlsx` file, the content as below:

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I googled export html table to csv file. and find this link :

[Export html table to CSV file](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/exporting-html-table-to-csv-file-using-jquery)

It's very helpful.

Note: I edit this code because my output file encoding was wrong. In "jquery.tabletoCSV.js" file, the following code need to change:

```
        var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
```

Instead top line code, I wrote:

```
        var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8,%EF%BB%BF' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
```

And encoding exported correctly.

Comment: Your encoding was OK, but Microsoft wants a BOM - Byte Order Mark - at the start of the file.